# C# VS 2012 Emulator not start

Tags: visual-studio-2012, hyper-v, windows-phone-8-emulator

I am facing problem, When I Debug project on Emulator it is not started. It gives me an error **The Windows Phone Emulator requires Hyper-V** and error code is **Error 0x80131500**

Error message.

[image]

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable Hyper‑V on Windows 8

In Control Panel, tap or click Programs, and then tap or click Programs and Features.

Tap or click Turn Windows Features on or off.

Select Hyper‑V, tap or click OK, and then tap or click Close.

Shut down your PC, and then restart it.

if option is disabled then you need to update bios settings for enabling it

[To check if you pc supports or not download and check it with this tool](http://slatstatuscheck.codeplex.com/) 
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick ans, But there is not showing Hyper-V in Windows Features on or off list.

Comment: download above tool to check if your pc supports or not? and btw which OS you are using ?

Answer (score 1):

To be able to install hyper-v you need to be running hardware that supports hyper-v (supports hardware virtualization, hardware D.E.P. and SLAT)

*You need, at minimum, **Windows 8.1 Professional 64 bit**, and at least 6 GB of RAM (obviously, the more the better).*

If you can't see Hyper-V in the Windows Features list that can be the result of the following:

- Your hardware doesn't support Hyper-V
- You don't have the right Windows version

If your hardware doesn't support SLAT you can run a 64 bit version of Windows Server (2008 R2 at minimum) and install Hyper-V there.

Hope this helps.